# Why can't I create an Excel VSTO workbook project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-2010

I try to create an Excel 2010 workbook project in Visual studio.  I go into Visual Studio and Choose new project and choose Excel 2010 Workbook and then i just get a pop up that says "The project cannot be created" with no other info

[image]

any suggestions why VS 2010 is not letting me create an Excel workbook project? (It does create an Excel addin project fine).  This error message above is not very helpful.  Given that the error message is not very helpful is there anyway to debug to get more information that would make this question easier to answer

Comment: It is not really possible to a real answer since I don't have a way to reproduce what you describe... BUT one thing comes to mind: a workbook projects contains an XLS(X) file... perhaps VS needs Excel on the same machine to do that... do you have Excel installed on your VS machine ?

Comment: @Yahia - understood.  Is there any logs or other stack trace / error messages i can get that would make this question easier to answer

Comment: Since I never had this problem I am not sure what logs/messages to look for... check the event log, if it is COM related it might be in there... do you have Excel on the same machine where you encounter this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error - in order to fix it, while in Excel I went to `Options -> Add-ins -> Manage Excel Add-ins -> Automation ->` and Selected "Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel".  Then restart Excel and (if you had the same issue) you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2015 and Office 2016.

It turned out to be [a bug introduced in latest updates of Office](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d327e21-3531-45f6-97dd-93c1baa7aeb0/).

To [revert back to an older revision](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770432), open an Administrator Command Prompt and type:

```
cd %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun
officec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.6965.2063
```

See:

- [Error: The project cannot be created. (Excel 2016 VSTO Workbook)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d327e21-3531-45f6-97dd-93c1baa7aeb0/)
- [How to revert to an earlier version of Office 2013 or Office 2016 Click-to-Run](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770432)
- [Version and build numbers of update channel releases for Office 365 clients](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592918.aspx#BKMK_ByVersion)

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as administrator. Helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Attention in VS2013: These are Com-Addins, no "Addins", and they are loaded on startup. Do not alter anything in Add-ins ... Automation!

- uninstall VSTO 2010 (das ist das für Office 2007  / 2010 / 2013 !)
- reboot
- repair Office 2010
- reboot
- reinstall VSTO
- reboot
- Check, if there is a

  - C:\Users_USERNAME_\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.xslb

  and remove it (rename XLSTSTART)
- Startmenu -> VS2013 -> VS-Tools ->   Developer Command Prompt VS2103
  (not native!) - as admin !

  - probably delete folder c:\user...\documents\VisualStudio
  - devenv /resetuserdata
  - devenv /setup
- Open   Developer Command Prompt VS2103 (not native!) as user

  - probably delete folder c:\user...\documents\VisualStudio
  - devenv /resetuserdata
  - devenv /setup
    devenv /resetsettings

Voilá

Greets Axel

Answer (score 0):

Doing what Kevin did, is evident, but it didn't do the trick alone. I realized that I had two installations of Office. I deleted the one in english. Didn't help. Read somewhere that I should try to have same language on office and VSTO. Uninstalled the danish version of Office and reinstalled the english version and now it works like a charm.